# How to clear activity from activity stack that has been started from outside the activity in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-stack

I have a broadcast receiver class that starts  some dialog activity say A with the intent flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK as i am starting activity from outside Activity(Even when my app is not running) and everyone do the same. 
**

### case :

**
i run my app and closed it.some event trigger broadcast and broadcast receiver will catch and  start dialog activity A then user cancel it by finishing it.**Here is the problem:** user try to lunch app from home button  then Dialog activity opens up instead of main activity.

any suggestion will be appreciated.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can check intent [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP), [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY) or [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK).

Comment: thanks for quick response but i have already tried it and didn't worked :(

Comment: @chrish, I have updated my answer. Perhaps, it could help. Thanks.

Comment: thanks. but it didn't worked out. But i manage to escape out from this problem by declaring  android:excludeFromRecents="true" on dialog activity in manifest file.